# image of uitableviewcell is stretching

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Below is how I initialize the style for a cell

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        .................................................
        .................................................
        // Set size for imageView
        CGRect  frame               =   self.imageView.frame;
        frame.size.width            =   16;
        frame.size.height           =   16;
        self.imageView.frame        =   frame;
    }

    return self;
}
```

However, after setting an image to imageview of a cell, the image is stretching now. The size of original is 24x24.

[image]

How can I make an image look shape ?

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use imageView property of the cell, but create your own imageview and add it

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:neededImage];
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,16,16);
[self addSubview:myImageView];
[myImageView release];
```

The original problem is that imageView property is `If an image is set, it appears on the left side of the cell, before any label.` So cell stretches it as it is used to behave.